# Get Value of another Column in Datatables.net

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, datatables, razor-pages

I am using datatables.net in my Code and I have a scenario where I need to pass value of some other column in render function of another column in a javascript as parameter. I have tried with row.columnname but I am getting undefined when trying to view the value.

Below is my code. Any help on this will be very useful.

Inside Ajax under columns section while binding datatables.net with my data

`columns :[` {"data":"test1"}
`{"data":"test2"}` {
`"data" :"test3"` ,"render":function(data,row)
`{` return xyz(row.test1, row.test2) //calling another javascript function with other 2 column values. Also getting row.test1 and row.test2 as undefined. Need proper value of test1 and test2
`}` }]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you were nearly there. The [`render` function](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) provides 4 arguments (`data`, `type`, `row`, `meta`) - what happens if you try this:

```js
  ...
  columns: [
    {
      "data": "test1"
    }, {
      "data": "test2"
    }, {
      "data" :"test3",
      "render": function(_ ,_, row) {
        return xyz(row.test1, row.test2)
      }
    }
  ],
  ...
```

Perhaps try and work up a JSFiddle or something to illustrate what you've got, we'd be better placed to help if we can see what you're seeing.

Comment: I was able to get the value using the code 
 `...
  `columns: [
  `   {
  `    "data": "test1"
  `   }, {
  `    "data": "test2"
  `   }, {
  `    "data" :"test3",
  `    "render": function(index , row, data) {
  `      return xyz(data['test1]+_+data['test2'])
  `    }
  `  }
  `],
`...
But the problem is the value displaying on the UI is Test1_Test2 instead of test3

Comment: Aye, the render function means you display what is returned from it, rather than `test3` - if you need to do something with the value from a function I think you probably need to use a [rowCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) - perhaps work up a JSFiddle to illustrate what you want?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried with row.columnname but I am getting undefined when
> trying to view the value.

Try to changne `row.test1` into  `row['test1']`

Comment: With this approach the data for test1 is getting binded in test3 in the datatables